# Unable to select from dropdrop using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I am having the issue to select drop down in GWT application and I am thinking its because of below setting at bootstrap class="bootstrap-select form-control bs-select-hidden"

Any body made it working ?? Even though the field is displayed on the page, Selenium driver thinks its not displayed.

Using Cucumber/Selenium/Java

Comment: show your code, what you are trying

Comment: I am trying to select a value from drop down and below is html on page (below in one of the thread and sorry its not in good format) and my code to select.                                                                                                                ExpectedBehaviors.expectPresenceofElementBy(_businessUnit,
                getElementTimeout()).click();

        ExpectedBehaviors.expectPresenceofElementBy(_businessUnit,
                getElementTimeout()).sendKeys(businessUnit);

Comment: Any further comment on this issue ??

Comment: show how are you using `class="bootstrap-select form-control bs-select-hidden"` to select

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap select class is annoying to work with.

There is a hidden value that the bootstrap select control will bindto, what you can easily do is set this hidden value, and send a javascript change event.

In the source you'll see something like,

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    ...
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

For example, on this page, https://select2.github.io/examples.html
Notice the `<select>` element called 'js-example-basic-single' is hidden.  This is storing the value.  So in Selenium, you can use executeScript() method to trigger this.

You can execute javascript to force set the value and trigger the change event to trigger the actions on that control.

```
driver.execute_script("$('.js-example-basic-single').val('HI').trigger('change');return true;")
```

Comment: <select id="gwt-debug-BusinessUnit" class="bootstrap-select form-control bs-select-hidden" name="BusinessUnit">
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" data-id="gwt-debug-BusinessUnit" title="Nothing selected">
<div class="dropdown-menu open">
</div>

Comment: Thanx David for quick reply. Above is the html for the web page. There is no java scripts its a bootstrap class and properties are hidden by default. I have printed isDisplayed value and its false. Not sure, how can I expose the list items, so that Selenium will be able to select them.